# Jenkins unable to read config.xml: hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm

Tags: jenkins

Using Jenkins 2.169

A Jenkins server suddenly failed today with the following error:

```
SEVERE: Failed Loading global config
java.io.IOException: Unable to read /somewhere/jenkins/home/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:181)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:161)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3043)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1300(Jenkins.java:309)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$13.run(Jenkins.java:3145)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1096)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy :   hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
    cause-exception     :   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
    cause-message       : hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
    class               : hudson.model.Hudson
    required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
    converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
    path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
    line number         : 12
    version             : not available
    -------------------------------
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:354)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:268)
    at  com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1189)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:161)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:132)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1173)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:178)
    ... 12 more
    Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
```

Found out that the culprit were two missing plugins:
    `matrix-auth`
    `ldap`

I could recover Jenkins, by manually copying the plugins from another server. Files copied:

```
jenkins/home/plugins/matrix-auth
jenkins/home/plugins/matrix-auth.jpi
jenkins/home/plugins/ldap
jenkins/home/plugins/ldap.jpi
```

First, I installed matrix-auth. Then I got the following error that indicated that ldap was also having issues:

```
Caused by: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException:
hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm : hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm
---- Debugging information ----
message             : hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm
cause-exception     :   
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/securityRealm
line number         : 53
version             : not available
-------------------------------
```

After further investigation found out that lots of plugins got deleted (also, I found out the culprit and it is NOT related to Jenkins).  So part of the solution was to copy the entire plugin directory from another Jenkins server.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I remember I had to copy the plugins (luckily, I had another Jenkins server with the same configuration, so I just copied the missing plugins).

Answer (score 1):

It happened because your config file syntax is incorrect.

```
sudo service jenkins stop

mv config.xml config.xml_bkp

sudo service jenkins start
```

this will fix it as it will create new config.xml in the jenkins directory on your master server

Comment: This worked for me. Note that jenkins will know about any of your jobs or configuration anymore. You'll have to either fix your config or re-create them manually.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while trying to update Jenkins while having an old version of Matrix Authentication Strategy.

I was terrified of a downtime on the service (we didn't have a good staging environment). But everything went well after updating the plugin to its latest version and then updating Jenkins too.

Comment: How to update plugins can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with this issue.
I upgraded the jenkins from 2.377 to 2.433
and jenkins refused to start with the same error as you experienced.
What I did was like this to resolve the issue.
Take a backup of config.xml
Open config.xml and
Changed
--- useSecurity true useSecurity  to
----useSecurity false useSecurity
And removed everything from
---<authorizationStrategy
----class="hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy">
.....
until the second appearance of
----/securityRealm>

systemctl stop jenkins
systemctl start jenkins
Update the plugin that is shown in the right corner of the jenkins home page

Then upgrade the jenkins and verify that no more warnings are shown.
Finally copy the config.xml backup to config.xml
And restart jenkins
And it's done.